# C# Query Active Directory with a custom Property in .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, userprincipal

How can I query the Active Directory of my Company with a custom property in .NET Standard2.0?
For example, if I want to query with a given property, my code looks like:

```cs
FSharpOption<UserPrincipal> TryGetUser(SecurityIdentifier sid)
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Sid, sid.Value);
        if (user == null)
            return FSharpOption<UserPrincipal>.None;

        return FSharpOption<UserPrincipal>.Some(user);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to query with a custom property named `"manager"` which is a string. I want to search for all users having the `manager == "..."`.

Comment: im pretty sure you will have to create a custom string filter in order to do that. it will look something like this (&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user))

Comment: You actually can extend the UserPrincipal class to do this (along with overriding Find method(s)).  See SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24798037/2788458)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with `UserPrincipal`, and `PrincipalSearcher` will only let you search by the properties exposed by `UserPrincipal`. You have to use [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher) directly (which is what `PrincipalSearcher` uses behind the scenes anyway).

Here is an example of what you would do:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUsersWithManager(string managerDn) {
    var search = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry()) {
        Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(manager={managerDn}))"
    };
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

    using (var results = search.FindAll()) {
        foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
            if (result.Properties.Contains("mail")) {
                yield return (string) result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The parameter is the manager's `distinguishedName` and it returns the `distinguishedName` of any users who have that person as their manager (the `manager` attribute contains the DN of the manager's account). You may need to adjust it for your needs.

If you need a `UserPrincipal` object for the resulting users, you can do that with this (where the `distinguishedName` variable is the DN of the user):

```
UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, distinguishedName)
```

Just keep in mind that the [`manager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-manager) attribute is not indexed. So if that is your only criteria (besides `(objectClass=user)`), then AD needs to look at *every* user to find matches. That may or may not be really slow in your environment.

Personally, I prefer using `DirectorySearcher` and `DirectoryEntry` directly anyway. I find the whole `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace to be really slow. I wrote an article about how to speed up performance using the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace directly: [Active Directory: Better Performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

Comment: You actually can extend the UserPrincipal class to do this (along with overriding Find method(s)).  See SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24798037/2788458)

Comment: @PBMe_HikeIt If you want, sure. But using `DirectorySearcher`/`DirectoryEntry` *always* performs faster than `PrincipalSearcher`/`UserPrincipal` anyway.